# In RabinKarp Algorithm why compare hash first?

Tags: algorithm, rabin-karp

In Rabin Karp substring search algorithm :

1) Calculate hash of the substring
2) Take a sliding window [equals the size of substring] and compare the hash of the string present in the window to that of substring.
3) If hash matches then we compare window content with the substring.

**Question:**
1) What is the benefit in terms of performance by matching hash first rather and then comparing ? Why we cannot just compare ? Comparing hash can be faster but how (i didn't get) ?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article and in particular the section on a rolling hash function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: @IanMercer : oh yes i read about the rolling hash function as well... it got struck in my mind that we can compare string with substring in a rolling fashion..Thanks anyways now things are pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the window slides, it only takes `O(1)` time to compute the new hash, and `O(1)` time to compare hashes.

Doing a full string comparison would take up to `O(m)` time every time you slide the window, where `m` is the length of the substring, and is likely to suffer from branch misprediction.

Comment: ohh..yes ....thanks !! Some how it got struck in my mind that we can compare string with substring in a rolling fashion...